# match-case: Bind keyword attribute to variable

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing, structural-pattern-matching

When matching against a [class-pattern](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#class-patterns) with keyword attributes, is it possible to bind the attribute to a variable directly?

For positional arguments, it is possible via walrus operator: https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#walrus-patterns

```py
import ast
tree = ast.parse('foo.bar = 2')
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    match node:
        case ast.Attribute(value=ast.Name()):
            # how to bind value directly?
            print(node)
            print(value)  # name value is not defined
```

One could of course do something like `case ast.Attribute(value=ast.Name()) as attr` and then use `attr.value`, but `mypy` doesn't like this and claims that `attr.value` is an `expr` and not an `ast.Name`.

```py
match node:
    case ast.Attribute(value=ast.Name()) as attr:
        name: str = attr.value.id  # mypy: "expr" has no attribute "id"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out we can use `as`-pattern even inside the class pattern

```py
import ast
tree = ast.parse('foo.bar = 2')
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    match node:
        case ast.Attribute(value=ast.Name() as value) as attr:
            print(attr)
            print(value)
```